# Even after I deleted an answer on my own question, the bounty required is still 100

Tags: bug, support, status-bydesign, bounty

I recently posted [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229664/portable-brainfuck-interpreter-in-ansi-c) about a brainfuck interpreter in ANSI C.

I answered my own question, but then realized that my answer was invalid, so I removed it.

I then wanted to add a bounty to my question to draw attention to it. However, it now will require 100 reputation instead of the usual 50.

Is this intended? If not, can it be fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The help center has [the following note about bounties](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on
>   a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum
>   spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

I don't know whether it is by design, or if it is a bug, that your deleted post is being counted as a posted answer. I can see reasons for both (it'd be really easy to undelete your answer and get a "cheap" bounty)...

I am going to go with "by design" in order to prevent abuse.

Having said that, it's kind of a nice question... I will add my own rep to a bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the offer! I guess I do see the potential for abuse here... I wasn't thinking about that when I posted here.

Comment: @JL2210 - bounty added.... also, we sorto of get used to looking for the edge-cases as mods ;-)

Comment: @JL2210 - by adding the bounty, I get to choose which answer to assign it to. I forgot that is a problem. I have a long-standing offer to put bounties on decent questions that need attention, if asked.... and I let the bounty run to the end, to draw maximum attention (I don't just award it to the first answer). If you would prefer to do the assignment, I can withdraw my bounty, and you can add your own.

Comment: I can just accept the answer and let you know here. If I forget to let you know by the end of the week (which I'm terrible with with bounties), you can just award it to the most-upvoted or accepted answer.

Comment: No problem, works for me  ;-)

Comment: Whoops, forgot to let you know or accept the answer. I see that you awarded the bounty anyway. Thank you!